# Site won't open in Facebook App for ios, nor redirect to Safari

Tags: ios, facebook, html, uiwebview, safari

I'm not a heavy coder here, so i'll ask my best.

We made a brochure about our home town. However users spreading it trough facebook cant open the links when in their facebook app. The app does not send it to safari either. If opened directly from safari it is no problem.

The link is http://visit.lodingen360.com

Is there anything i can do to the site/index.html/whatever that will make it open in safari when the link is clicked in the facebook app for ios? (that won't affect visiting the site from pc's and so on)

Is there anything uiwebview won't read that can force it to safari, so that we can redirect from the thing opened in safari to the site?

Comment: Is this website also used as a mobile web app?

Comment: Are you trying to get it to open your native app?

Comment: "The app does not send it to safari". Which app? Why did you put a tag of UIWebVIew? If you are using UIWebView show how you are using it.

Comment: Sorry my incompetence, but here is the scenario. A user surfs facebook with the Facebook-app on his ipad2. (not in safari) He spots the link and clicks it. It does not open. It does not open safari to open the link either.

I put a tag of uiwebview becouse of what i could read, this is (by my understanding) the thingy that show webstuff when surfing facebook in the facebook-app. However, i can not reprogram og reconfigurate a app i did not make my self, that millions of users are using.

Comment: So i put the tag fo attract atteintion from someone that understands uiwebview and could maybe tell me how to "trick" it to open the link in safari.

The link works fine in safari, but not in the facebook-app (facebook-reader-kinda-app. Dedicated app for surfing facebook). I don't know how to describe it better.

Comment: Omar: No. Just a page.

TheDeveloper: Yes. OR to make the native app open safari to view the page.

Answer (score 1):

Your page will load and display in Mobile Safari, I tried with UIWebView and it will load without displaying an error, but the brouchure page content won't display.

Safari and UIWebView have different user agent's - therefore my guess is that because your site uses flash but it checking for the type of browser you are not performing the check correctly for UIWebView and the page is attempting to use flash which isn't supported.

Comment: Great answer! However the site is in flash, and html. Html5 for mobile support. I think too this is the problem, so i guess it's just having to wait for facebook to fix their app. If there is'nt any reconfiguration of the index-file i can do to make a workaround that is.. I was thinking adding an image to the link, since some users click the image, not the link, and trough that redirect to something that opens safari, and then redirects to the page of the brochure. This would only help those who click the image.. Sigh! Thanx for great answers peeps! Really appreciated ;)

Comment: But if your site can be viewed on Mobile Safari it must be switching to HTML5 when it detects that browser. I think it is a problem with your site not with facebook - I had a quick look and it seems your website source code is checking which browser it is on and toggling between html5 or flash, this is working for Mobile Safari but not for UIWebView. So if you change that code to take account of the UIWebView it should work.

Comment: Thanx! I have submitted this discussion to the company making the software, hopefully they easily spot the problem, i mean, even i could understand this last post here, so i it hopefuly simple enough to solve. Again, big thanx for you help! I'm a little wiser now, and thats cool!